# ¿Qué es `it` en Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Por ejemplo, rellenando un array de desperfectos con datos de otro array:

```
if (datosAccidente.desperfectos.isNotEmpty()) {
  rDesperfectos = datosAccidente.desperfectos.map { Desperfecto(it) }
}
```

o al leer las líneas de un fichero:

```
File("./miFichero.txt").forEachLine { println(it) }
```

¿Qué es `it` y qué representaría en esos ejemplos?

Leyendo [la documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter), se menciona que `it` es un nombre implícito para un parámetro único, pero entonces ¿por qué no funcionaría para un caso como el siguiente?:

```
fun test(datos: String) {
  var aux: String = it
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la documentación que enlazas pone:

> A lambda expression or an anonymous function is a "function literal"

*Una expresión lambda o función anónima es una "función literal"*

Y en la definición de `it` explica:

> One other helpful convention is that if a **function literal** has only one parameter, its declaration may be omitted (along with the ->), and its name will be `it`

*Otra útil convención es que si una función literal sólo tiene un parámetro, su declaración puede ser omitida (junto con el ->) y su nombre será `it`*.

Por tanto `it` es una convención para que la declaración de las funciones lambda sea aún mas breve.

Esto no funciona con la función declarada del modo *clásico*

```
fun test(datos: String) {
  var aux: String = it
}
```

porque la sintaxis requiere explícitamente el nombre de la variable **y su tipo**: La función test se puede usar de modo general, con lo que el compilador no puede inferir el tipo si no se define en este momento, mientras que las funciones lambda se declaran en el momento en el que se van a usar (tienen un contexto muy definido) y, por tanto, el tipo no se tiene que definir de manera explícita.